# Update a plugin without having the source code

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

is possible to update a plugin without having the source code?I managed to disassemble the dll and re-build a working solution but I have problems with the signing key. Is there a way to work around this, and update the existing plugin, or will i need to remove the plugin from the crm and re-deploy the new one with the new key?

Comment: I think you will have to remove and re-deploy as the strong name keys won't match, which in the Microsoft space is treated as a different versions even if the name and assembly version numbers are the same.

Comment: I thought so, I was interested in a way to recover the key :) I will be able to do it, but sometimes you are not so lucky, especially in a context where the solution is managed.